# Exception when Ignite in Client mode is stopped : Failed to deserialize object with given class loader

Tags: java, marshalling, ignite

When even I stop the **Ignite** started in client mode, I get exception as follow:

```
[tcp-client-disco-sock-reader-#3%null%] ERROR (Log4JLogger.java:495)
   - Failed to read message
[sock=Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=47500,localport=36657], 
    locNodeId=67dc56ee-cc09-4fc2-9852-39639fca58e0, 
    rmtNodeId=1d8a7595-b549-45b3-a1d0-edc21c14fd43]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize
    object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3485def8
```

Please tell me a way to fix this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When node stops or fails, you can sometimes get this exception due to closed connection. If this happens only when node stops and if this doesn't cause any issues, it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: Hello, but stop my processing, I see no other errors but this.